# How do I recycle my earlier question which is flagged?

Tags: support

Earlier I posted a question which is flagged as it is inappropriate and I could not delete it due to answered. Now I changed both the title and content see link below, my question is since the new question is entirely different from the original flagged question is this recycling of question allowed? The comments and answer posted for original question is irrelevant to the new question is there any advise what to do with them?

[Is negative energy a consequence of gravitational energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171818/is-negative-energy-a-consequence-of-gravitational-energy)

Answer (score 2):

No, this sort of recycling is not allowed. In general, any edit which completely changes the essential nature of a question is not allowed, because - as you noticed - it invalidates existing answers, and it also messes things up for people who may have bookmarked the question to come back to it later, and so on. If you want to completely change a question, just post a new question.

Editing an answer to change it completely is not so bad, but only if you are the one who originally posted the answer, and it's rather discourteous if someone else's answer references yours. So, let's say, try not to do that very much.

Any time an edit invalidates *comments*, that's fine. Just flag one of the comments as obsolete.

---

In this case you should also roll back the edit that completely changed your question.

Comment: May I request for that affected question to be removed instead, it would seem pointless to restore an inappropriate question on this site as it only invites more downvote for me. Sorry for the inconvenience, thank you.

Comment: @user6760 we don't delete content on request, but if a "delete" link appears at the lower left corner of the question, you can do it yourself. If you don't see the link, it means that the question can't be deleted.

Comment: Since that question has an upvoted answer, you will not be able to delete the question. (This is by design: deleting the question also deletes the answer, which is ill payment to Alfred's patience in stopping by to answer.) Honestly, though, it doesn't matter that much. The question is closed and will not be visible to people unless they are specifically looking for it, so you're not 'fouling up' the site. Just move on and be more careful next time.